# VS Code transition:background-color not working

Tags: css, transition, highlight

In VS Code When I add "transition : background-color" it's not highlighted and not working either. The same error occurred to me when I was adding the animation. Can anyone please explain to me, why this is happening? I have included image links below.

[image of " transition:background-color " (not highlighted and not working)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fa7KH.png)

[image of animation (not highlighted and not working)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHghI.png)

[image where I declared animation properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASKKf.png)

Comment: don't post images of code

Comment: There is no problem actually that's how it works with the latest updates.